# How can I apply CDATA in XML for webservices in asp.net?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, xml-parsing, ashx

How can I apply CDATA here in such XML of web services in asp.net, as in

```
<booktitle> data </booktitle>
```

I have some symbols like '&', which resist me to parse it to Android.

Here is my code:

```
for (int iBookResponse = 0; iBookResponse < dataTable.Rows.Count; iBookResponse++)
                {
                    DataRow dataRow = dataTable.Rows[iBookResponse];

                    xmlResponse += "<Book>";
                    xmlResponse += "<BookID>" + dataRow["book_id"].ToString() + "</BookID>";
                    xmlResponse += "<BookCode>" + dataRow["book_code"].ToString() + "</BookCode>";
                    xmlResponse += "<BookTitle>" + dataRow["book_title"].ToString()+ "</BookTitle>";
                   xmlResponse += "</Book>";

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just prepend `xmlResponse` with `<![CDATA[` and append `]]>` to it. So your `xmlResponse` can start with

```
xmlResponse += "<![CDATA[<Book>";
```

and end it with

```
  xmlResponse += "</Book>]]>"
```

with everything else in between.